# Post notification with sender and object

Tags: objective-c, object, notifications, sender

I cannot seem to find out how to post a notification with an object and a sender.

I can post a notification with a name, sender and user info. See:

```
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName
                      object:(id)notificationSender
                    userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

And I can post a NSNotification with an object, but not link an sender to it:

```
NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:name
                                                             object:someObject];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
```

Can anybody tell me how to post a notification with (a) a object and (b) a sender reference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In both methods you propose, the `object` variable represents the sender of the notification, which can be anything you want really. To provide additional objects with the notification, you could pass a dictionary with your objects to `userInfo`.

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      someObject, @"someObject",
                                      anotherObject, @"anotherObject", nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:name
                                                    object:sender
                                                  userInfo:options];
```

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, but i would like a more generic solution without key-value. But it will do for now. Thanks

Comment: That's simply not possible using the `NSNotification` API. This actually is the generic solution, they made it possible to provide an additional number of objects.

Comment: With generic i mean that you have to provide a key for the object you provide. When just adding one object to the NSNotification, other classes in your project will not have to know what key is used, because none is used. But thanks for your answer.